# How can I use the Work while tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, freeze

Function running tkinter freezes.
I want to use the Tkinter window running that process.While running progress bar
i want use tkinter window.but I can not
because it freezes tkinter.**how can i use root window while time.sleep(10) or another function working**

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time

progress = 0


def loading(window=None):
    mpb = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
    mpb.place(y=0, x=0)
    mpb["maximum"] = 100
    mpb["value"] = progress
    print(progress)


def incrase():
    global progress
    print(progress)
    progress += 1
    time.sleep(10)  # for example, a function works here and tkinter freezes
    loading()       # i don't want tkinter freezes


root = tk.Tk()
loading(root)
ttk.Button(root, text='increase', command=incrase).place(x=0, y=25, width=90)

root.mainloop()
```

thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)  with which  you can  schedule the `loading()` function to be called after some period of time.

## Program

Here is how you can use it in your program:

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time

progress = 0


def loading(window):
    mpb = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate")
    mpb.place(y=0, x=0)
    mpb["maximum"] = 100
    mpb["value"] = progress
    print(progress)


def incrase():
    global root
    global progress
    print(progress)
    progress += 1
    root.after(10, loading(root))  # schedule loading() 



root = tk.Tk()
loading(root)
ttk.Button(root, text='increase', command=incrase).place(x=0, y=25, width=90)

root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

Screenshot of the above running program:

[image]